# Python scraping hidden data

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to scrape text from an object but firstly I have to hover on it. Original code looks like:

```html
<app-tooltip-widget _nghost-tmf-c12="">
    <div _ngcontent-tmf-c12="" triggers="" class="">
        <img alt="Info icon" class="img-fluid shipments-info-icon" src="info.png">
    </div>
</app-tooltip-widget>
```

When i hover on it:

```html
<app-tooltip-widget _nghost-sqv-c21="">
    <div _ngcontent-sqv-c21="" triggers="" class="" aria-describedby="tooltip-21">
        <img alt="Info icon" class="img-fluid shipments-info-icon" src="info.png">
        </div>
    </app-tooltip-widget>
```

Appear 'aria-describedby="tooltip-21"'
I need scrape information inside
Im trying:

```html
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('example.com')
driver.maximize_window()

men_menu = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@_ngcontent-sqv-c21=""]')))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(men_menu).perform()

data = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@aria-describedby="tooltip-23"]').text
print(data)
```

Comment: Did you try using `WebDriverWait` for the `data` variable? Instead of `driver.find_element_by_xpath`

Comment: Same. Result is not nothing but new lane.

Comment: What do u wanna scrape from this? What is the desired output?

Comment: Can you please share the URL to the site? Makes it easy for some of us to test out different techniques.